# Error trapping within a large PDO sqlite transaction

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am parsing a text file into an empty sqlite database for processing the file data using php. I establish the database connection with:

```
try {
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:temp.db');
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  die($error);
}
```

As the user file data is large, unsequenced and has multiple internal foreign key dependencies, I insert the data as a single transaction using DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED on my foreign keys. This works well as long as my original input data is correct. When a user input error occurs I get a single generic exception for the whole transaction (which of course then rolls back). The user error often, but not exclusively, manifests itself as an undefined foreign key reference.

Can anyone suggest a way of getting more information e.g. the individual insert statement in the transaction that caused the exception, or the specific foreign key that was missing, that would aid in tracking down the user input error?

As there is no sequence to the user input data and that data is complex in its structure it would be very involved to validate it prior to the commit, I would like to avoid manually coding that aspect if possible.

Comment: This question isn't very clear; you would get better help if you shared some of the code that actually does inserting stuff; table structures may help as well.

Comment: @Jack I fail to see why you need to see the table structure to understand the question. The problem is clearly stated that a foreign key exception is hard to locate within a large transaction. Jason did manage to grasp the exact problem and propose a coded solution. It is now apparent that there is no SQLite/PDO solution.

Comment: Please check both error reports: db handle and statement. and add them to your question. +1 @Jack

Comment: Without that, I can only conclude that if your foreign key checks happen at commit (which is what I understand is the meaning of deferred), this is basically expected behaviour; is there a reason why it must be deferred?

Comment: He's receiving an unordered (and not easily ordered) block of data which may have rows with primary keys entered after rows entered with foreign keys that rely on those primary keys.  It's nowhere near an ideal situation, but I can conceive of situations where this might be my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// $queries is a query by query array of your insert data

// we'll assume any sub-arrays are initialized appropriately on demand
$primary_keys = array();
$foreign_keys = array();

foreach ($queries as $idx => $data) {
    // build your query appropriately

    // if this is an insert to a table with a primary key
    // that will be referenced by a foreign key:
        $primary_keys[$table_inserting_to][$idx] = $data['primary_key']; // the primary key value we're inserting

    // elseif this is an insert to a table with a foreign key
    // that references a primary key that could fail:
        $foreign_keys[$table_inserting_to][$idx] = $data['foreign_key']; // the foreign key value we're inserting

    // run your query
}

// commit your transaction

// whoops, we failed
// build the associations we need to check
$links = array('table_with_foreign_key' => 'table_with_primary_key', 'table_with_foreign_key_2' => 'table_with_primary_key_2');
$errors = array();
foreach ($links as $foreign => $primary) {
    $failed_keys = array_diff($foreign_keys[$foreign], $primary_keys[$primary]);
    foreach ($failed_keys as $key) {
        $errors[] = "Foreign key check $foreign to $primary, $key could not be found on query idx ".array_search($key, $foreign_keys[$foreign]);
    }
}
```

... If you need to account for primary keys that already exist in the database, you could always query them out to initialize the `$primary_keys` array.

Comment: Obviously, this only checks for foreign key errors.  Other errors *should* be catchable at the time they occur, only errors that result from foreign key validations are deferred.

Comment: I think this is a pretty good work-around, it's tough for me to implement as I have several 100 cross-referenced (foreign key) tables (some with multiple foreign key references) and more may get added, so building $links is quite a task - could this be constructed with a query of the db structure?

Comment: Jason, I'll give you the bounty as it gave a potentially, as elegant as it can be, solution. I was really hoping there was a better way to query the failed transaction, but I have since learnt this is not possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I haven't delved too deeply into what sort of meta information you can query out of SQLite, like an information_schema type structure.  Quick search leads to PRAGMA table_info(): http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info ... search down that path to see if you can query foreign key structures in place

Comment: Here you go: `SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';` in combination with `PRAGMA foreign_key_list(table-name);` http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you're using prepared statements

If it's not the case, you should make the necessary adjustments.

A. Collect the parameters inside an array

```
$params = array(':name' => 'foo', ':cat' => 'bar', ':val' => 'baz', [...]);
```

B. before calling `execute($params)`, do as follows, to register in a file the params you're using:

```
file_put_contents('file.log', implode(';', $params) . "\r\n"); //or "\n" on linux, "\r" on mac
```

C. call `execute($params)`

D. If the query is successful, GOTO A, otherwise, die.

With this simple algorithm you'll have a logfile (named `file.log`) with all the parameters which have been successfully inserted plus the wrong ones (at the last row).

**Possible improvement:**

This algorithm is not efficient, because you open and close the file multiple times. Follow these instructions instead if you care about efficiency:

X. Define `$log = array();`

A. Collect the parameters inside an array

```
$params = array(':name' => 'foo', ':cat' => 'bar', ':val' => 'baz', [...]);
```

B. before calling `execute($params)`, do as follows, to store the params you're using:

```
$log[] = implode(';', $params) . "\r\n"; //or "\n" on linux, "\r" on mac
```

C. call `execute($params)`

D. If the query is successful, GOTO A, otherwise, `file_put_contents('file.log', implode("\r\n", $log));`.

**Final consideration**

Combine the above suggestion with the PDO exception that's raised by the error. Its stack is always very useful for debugging purposes.

To enable exceptions with pdo, use this command after the connection:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Are you sure this will pick up deferred foreign key errors - as the keys are deferred they are only tested at the commit, not during the statement preparation. As you will see from my original post, I am using the PDO exception handling, but this does not provide detail of which part of the transaction failed, only the failure error (typically foreign key exception).

Comment: You should not use deferred foreign key errors, but instead enable them and insert your values in order to use correctly the foreign key relations. This way, you would be able to find who's breaking your script.

Comment: LOL if it were that simple... BTW it is not the errors that are deferred, but the validation - it is specifically for this case where you cannot be sure of supplying the foreign key inserts in the correct order.